# Check if a device has flashlight

Tags: android, eclipse, camera, widget, android-context

```
public class FlashLightActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Context context = this;
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

        // if device support camera?
        if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            //yes
            Log.i("camera", "This device has camera!");
        }else{
            //no
            Log.i("camera", "This device has no camera!");
        }


    }
}
```

This is a working code for Checking weather the application has `FlashLight` or not , but how can I use this code in an `appwidgetprovider` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are planing to use it inside any function like `onUpdate` or `onEnabled` etc of `Appwidgetprovider`, then all those functions have `context` as a input parameter. You can use that context for using `PackageManager` as you are doing here.

Also in your question you mention *`flashlight`*. So just check if you need `FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH` or `FEATURE_CAMERA`.

```
Context context = this;
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

// if device support flash?
if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
    //yes
    Log.i("camera", "This device has flash supported!");
}else{
    //no
    Log.i("camera", "This device has no flash support!");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In the the class (extends AppWidgetProvider).I have a method i want to be able to check if the device has flashlight from that method

Comment: You mean the capability of giving out flash light from its camera? I think that is what the code is doing? Isn't it?