# How do i make a validation about the missing flash camera on android?

Tags: java, android, mobile

Im making a flash aplication for a school proyect but my phone doesn't have an flashlight so.. i have a idea to make the validation if my phone dont have a flashlight so light up the screen.

can someone help me ? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this post may halp you to implement your idea:

> If you are planing to use it inside any function like `onUpdate` or
>   `onEnabled` etc of `Appwidgetprovider`, then all those functions have
>   `context` as a input parameter. You can use that context for using
>   `PackageManager` as you are doing here.
>
> Also in your question you mention *`flashlight`*. So just check if you
>   need `FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH` or `FEATURE_CAMERA`.
>
> ```
> Context context = this;
> PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
>
> // if device support flash?
> if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH))
> {
>     //yes
>     Log.i("camera", "This device has flash supported!");
>  }else{
>     //no
>     Log.i("camera", "This device has no flash support!");
>  }
> ```
>
> FROM: [Check if a device has flashlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242315/check-if-a-device-has-flashlight)

Check also:

- [how to check if device has flash light led android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413938/how-to-check-if-device-has-flash-light-led-android-A)
- [Android: how to check the flash light is available on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918561/android-how-to-check-the-flash-light-is-available-on-device)
- [[VUFORIA FORUM] check if flash light is present in device](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-3-extension-technical-discussion/check-if-flash-light-present-device)

Hope it help